# Universal Data Link Does not have MFA Option on Windows 10/11

Tags: sql-server, connectivity

In looking at the documentation [Universal Data Link (UDL) configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/help-topics/data-link-pages?view=sql-server-2016) (V2022/2019 & 2016), it says I can use a UDL file to attempt an `Active Directory - Universal with MFA support:` type login via the dropdown (*Section 2 in the dialogs below*).

But my version on a Windows 10 VM and my Windows 11 workstation does not have this option. What do I have to do, to get the option?

---

Left is (Windows 10/11 dialog) Right is the documentation view.

[image]

Comment: What provider did you select on the first tab?

Comment: The first tab was "Sql Server Native Client".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UDL configuration documentation link in your question is for [Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server). This is the latest SQL Server OLE DB driver and required for newer authentication options like Azure AD MFA.

The newer authentication options are not available when a deprecated driver is selected under the Providers tab (SQL Server Native Client or legacy Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server (SQLOLEDB)).

See the [Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server download page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server) for download links if you don't already have Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server (MSOLEDBSQL) installed.